# Problems connecting to node-network from a remote host with iptables firewall

Tags: docker, node-red, iptables

I have an ubuntu 22.04 LTS server with a container running nodered exposed on port 1880, I want to restringer with iptables. My configuration is as follows:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1880 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1880 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p all -j DOCKER-USER
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -o docker0 -j DOCKER
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i docker0 -o !docker0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp -i !docker0 -o docker0 -d 192.168.50.124 --dport 1880 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -p all -i docker0 -o !docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -p all -j RETURN

iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -p all -o docker0 -j DROP
iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -p all -j RETURN

iptables -A DOCKER-USER -p all -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

These are my iptables rules, what can I be doing wrong?

If I place: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT` & `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT`, it works

Comment: "restringer" means?

Answer (score 0):

this config should be enough:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1880 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1880 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure node-red container is started either attached to the host network, or attached to a docker bridge network, exposing port 1880. If you're exposing a different port, modify the iptables rules accordingly.